# make 2 dimensional array from string split

Tags: .net, vb.net, string

I'm not very familiar with the way vb handles arrays. But I have a string coming in that looks like:

```
Foo,4,7,12,,6|Bar,4,2,87,5,7|Fly,4,,87,5,7
```

and I need to end up with a 2 dimensional array where the 1st dimension is on the pipes and the 2nd on the commas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Dim splitThis = "Foo,4,7,12,,6|Bar,4,2,87,5,7|Fly,4,,87,5,7"
Dim splitAtPipe = splitThis.Split("|"c)
Dim result = splitAtPipe.Select(Function(x) x.Split(","c)).ToArray()
```

The last line is using LINQ to do a transformation on `splitAtPipe`. For every element in the array, it is selecting a new *thing* based on that element (the variable `x` in the lambda), in this case we are taking the element and transforming via `.Split()` into an string array, which becomes the new element in the result (i.e. whatever we return from that lambda/function becomes the new element). By default it return an `IEnumerable` so I called `ToArray()` to make it a two-dimensional array.

P.S. My explanation is probably not entirely accurate, but should be close enough for a basic understanding...

Comment: Brillant! I'll mark as accepted answer as soon as it will let me. If you have a minute could you explain what the final line is doing, I can't quite follow it.

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk sure it is. I looked at it in VS

Comment: @Casey, I added an explanation of the last line.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a jagged array:
Check that link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx

Proposed code in (VB.NET):

```
Imports System.IO

Class Program
    Private Shared Sub Main()

        Dim line As [String] = "Foo,4,7,12,,6|Bar,4,2,87,5,7|Fly,4,,87,5,7"
        Dim rows As [String]() = line.Split("|"C)
        Dim matrix As [String]()() = New [String](rows.Length - 1)() {}

        For i As Integer = 0 To rows.Length - 1
            matrix(i) = rows(i).Split(","C)
        Next

        Console.WriteLine(matrix(0)(0))
    End Sub
End Class
```

And the code should be something like that (in C#):

```
using System.IO;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {

        String line = "Foo,4,7,12,,6|Bar,4,2,87,5,7|Fly,4,,87,5,7";
        String[] rows = line.Split('|');
        String[][] matrix = new String[rows.Length][];

        for(int i =0; i<rows.Length; i++) {
            matrix[i] = rows[i].Split(',');
        }

       Console.WriteLine(matrix[0][0]);
    }
}
```